# kill an alarm checker in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I have an alarm checker in my activity (Groups.java) to start a service each few seconds:

```
public void lookForGroups()
    {
        int seconds = 40;

           Intent myIntent = new Intent(Groups.this, GroupsTaskAlarmChecker.class);
           pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Groups.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
           calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
           alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), seconds * 1000, pendingIntent);

    }
```

Also depending on sharedPreferences variable I start this service when I reboot device.

Is posible to "kill" or start that alarm checker depending of a value of a variable?
for example to automatically or manually sync my application.

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for mi english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand this...but you create an Alarm checker and want to kill it if it's already running?

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
```

should do it.  According to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), it will cancel any alarms with a matching intent

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but how can I interact with this variable if I am in another activity?(because in activity I dont have a constructor, only onCreate, onResume etc.). Thanks!

Comment: Ok I got it. I can call it for another activity if I declare a static function that contains "alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)".
Thanks again ;)